# C++ program crashes in the while loop when asked to use random number generator

Tags: c++, do-while

So I am trying to make a program which will generate random basic mathematical questions like addition, subtraction, etc.

While I am trying to generate division questions I made a do-while loop which runs until the prerequisite is met for division quesions.

But for some reason when I ask it to generate 20 division questions with none with remainder it always crashes.

Please help

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int correct,total,MAXVAL;
const char oper[4]={'/','/','/','/'};

typedef struct data{
    int first,second;
    char operation;
}data;

data datagenerator(){
    data newData;
    newData.first= (rand()%MAXVAL);
    newData.operation=oper[rand()%4];
    newData.second=(rand()%MAXVAL);
    return newData;
}

bool corrector(data newData){
    bool isture=false;
    switch(newData.operation){
        case '/':
            if((newData.first%newData.second)==0){
                isture=true;
            }
            break;
        case '*':
            isture=true;
            break;
        case '+':
            isture=true;
            break;
        case '-':
            isture=true;
            break;
    }
    return isture;
}

void quizer(){

    system("CLS");
    for(int counter=1;counter<=total;counter++){
        cout<<"Q"<<counter<<": ";
         data newData;
        do{
            newData=datagenerator();
        }while(!corrector(newData));
        cout<<newData.first<<newData.operation<<newData.second<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"\nYou got "<<correct<<"/"<<total<<"correct\n";
}


int main(){
    //srand((unsigned)time(0));
    char x;
    cout<<"How many questions do you want?"<<endl;
    cin>>total;
    cout<<"Enter the maximum value\n";
    cin>>MAXVAL;
    cout<<"Are you ready?\n";
    cin>>x;
    quizer();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem usually reveals itself when you can see a stack trace.  Fire up your favorite debugger, catch the failure and report back here.

Comment: can you post the one of the test cases?

Comment: I notice you're doing random numbers without using the `<random>` library. `rand()` is not as good if you don't have to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies right on line 17 and 19.  You are dividing by 0, assuming you are setting the value on MAXVAL to 0 when it asks you.  With modulo division you need to be careful with that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check for a division by 0.

```
bool corrector(data newData){
bool isture=false;
switch(newData.operation){
    case '/':
        if(newData.second == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if((newData.first%newData.second)==0){
            isture=true;
        }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your generating a 0 as a second number and then trying to use it to divide by a number.

you can put a check like this

```
if(newData.second == 0) {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Can't `rand()` return 0?  In that case, `(0 % MAXVAL-1)+1 == (0-1)+1 == -1+1 == 0`, no?